# Checking size of POST data in Apache

Tags: apache, logging

I have a script which takes POST data from an external application which then processes the data, this works fine when the POST data is small (i.e. 1-2MB).

We are now in a situation where we have much larger (40-50MB) data being sent up.

The data that is coming up is very basic, has a username, password and the actual data to process itself.

With the larger files, the PHP script is only seeing the username and password. There is no data key.

The application that is sending the data claims it is sending the full file.

I've tried mod_dumpio but not getting anything of any use (i.e. doesn't seem to be doing anything different on POST requests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post data was either being cut completely (in most cases) or partially truncated caused by suhosin. Increase the post max value length and request max value length solved the problem.